# rehydrate draft-js EditorState with redux-persist

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js, draftjs, redux-persist

I use `draft-js` in my React app, and I use `redux-persist` to rehydrate my state stored in localStorage.
I need to store my EditorState in my redux store, because storing the ContentState is not enough for me : the buttons to change the styles of my rich text editor are not located near to the real EditorState component. It is not a problem while I am working on it.
However, the problem exists when I need to rehydrate my data with `redux-persist` :  while the EditorState is properly saved in my redux store when I create it, looking like that :
[image]

when I reload the page and make `redux-persist` rehydrates, it then looks like that :

[image]

I should add that I have some immutable `Records` in my state, which I need to parse and all when I rehydrate my code with `redux-persist`, here is the code I use (I think the solution is there but I can't find out where exactly)

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { createTransform } from 'redux-persist';
import Serialize from 'remotedev-serialize';
import Immutable, { Record } from 'immutable';

const ExampleRecord = Record({
  anyData: 'here'
}, 'ExampleRecord')
/* 
For info, here is how would look the state
const state = {
  example: {
    record: ExampleRecord(),
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
  }
}
 */
const records = [
  ExampleRecord
]
const serializer = Serialize.immutable(Immutable, records);
const immutableTransform = createTransform(serializer.stringify, serializer.parse, {
  whitelist: ['example'],
});

export default {
  key: 'example',
  version: 0,
  storage,
  transforms: [immutableTransform],
};
```